# TSQL Where clause inside string query

Tags: sql, t-sql

My query:

```
SET @s_query =

'Select ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ' + @ColNames + ') AS ##RowNum, 
'+@ColNames+' INTO ##Results' +
' From TableA
Where FirstName = ' +@Search+ ' 
ORDER BY FirstName';
```

I am running the stored procedure with parameters:

```
@Search = 'Adam', @ColName = 'FirstName','LastName'
```

And getting the error:

```
" Invalid column name 'Adam'.
```

Comment: Do you mean `@ColName = '''FirstName','LastName'''`? If that's not the prob please paste the full sql and dump of @s_query.

Comment: Alex those are just parameters problem is in the where clause with which i am getting an error when running the SP. It assumes 'Adam' is a column

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you're just not quoting your string. The way your code comes out, to SQL it looks like:

```
Where FirstName = Adam
```

But you want it to look like:

```
Where FirstName = 'Adam'
```

So you'd want to change that line of your code to give it the single-quotes it needs. See the modified codeset below:

```
SET @s_query =

'Select ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ' + @ColNames + ') AS ##RowNum, 
'+@ColNames+' INTO ##Results' +
' From TableA
Where FirstName = ''' +@Search+ ''' 
ORDER BY FirstName';
```

Now your query will read:

```
Select ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY FirstName, LastName) AS ##RowNum,       
FirstName, LastName INTO ##Results From TableA      
Where FirstName = 'Adam'       
ORDER BY FirstName, LastName
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem appears to be where you specify the criteria for `FirstName`, you have:

```
Where FirstName = ' +@Search+ '
```

Which will literally be translated to:

```
Where FirstName = Adam
```

Note the missing quote around the search criteria `Adam`.

Try this instead, to ensure the additional quotes are included:

```
Where FirstName = ''' +@Search+ '''
```

Which will finally give:

```
Where FirstName = 'Adam'
```

Answer (score 0):

Others have already pointed out the missing quotes around the string criteria (= Adam, instead of = 'Adam').

I use a different technique to build the SQL to call, by constructing a template and replacing "parameters":

```
declare @s_QueryTemplate = 
'  
Select ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY <<ORDER BY COLUMN NAMES>>) AS ##RowNum, <<COLUMN NAMES>>   
INTO ##Results
From TableA
Where FirstName = ''<<SEARCH VALUE>>''
ORDER BY FirstName
'

SET @s_query =
REPLACE(
REPLACE(
REPLACE(
          @s_QueryTemplate   
        , '<<ORDER BY COLUMN NAMES>>', @ColNames
       ), '<<COLUMN NAMES>>', @ColNames
       ), '<<SEARCH VALUE>>', @Search
       )
```

I find this makes it much easier to see the structure of the code you're trying to create, including things like where there should be quotes.